# Issue with updating value in localStorage

Tags: javascript

i have an object stored in `localStorage` lets say `myObject`, when ever i get this object then update a key inside of it then try to use `localStorage.setItem` to update it, it updated all the keys inside that object.

the object keys are unique since they are reflecting other object IDs.

example code:

```
let obj = localStorage.getItem('myObject') || '{}'
obj = JSON.parse(obj)
obj[this.currentItem.id] = 'some value here'
localStorage.setItem('myObject', JSON.stringify(obj)) // updates all keys inside the object to be the same value
```

Comment: Since you've narrowed the problem to just this code, can you complete the example?  Before this code, set your object in `localStorage` with your keys.  After this code, fetch the object again and display it.  Demonstrating the problem will help us to see what's happening.

Comment: I don't see any way that the code you've posted could do that. The problem is most likely somewhere else.

Comment: I tested your code in a jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/1d3xm24e/) and it works as it should. So your problem is elsewhere

Comment: i am actually gonna go crazy cuz of this issue, when i manually modify the values and read then refresh my page to see if `localStorage.getItem` will work, it works correctly with no issues, its just this part where i update the values :/

Comment: @opllama: If your code demonstrably works and you can't create a test in which it fails then it sounds like the problem isn't what/where you assume it is.  We'd like to help, but without an example of the problem there isn't much we can do.

Answer (score 0):

ok i think i knew where the problem for this was but i don't know why it was happening, i am using Vue for my app and in the `mounted` function i was getting the item details using the `id` passed in the route, when i tried to `console.log(this.item)` it was fine until i redirected to another item then it started to log all the items i have already been through in this page before, i have no idea why this is happening, this triggered the `localStorage.setItem` multiple times with different IDs but the same value i had which ended up updating all the keys in object inside the `localStorage` as well.

i ended up using the id from the route `this.$route.params.id` instead and that solved it but i still have no idea why the mounted was triggering multiple times like this and why it was triggering with different object everytime :/

if this is something in Vue about rendering and lifecycle and someone knows why, could you please link some articles so i can read about it, i am still starting in Vue.